# Chartsjs multi-axis, make the scale appear/disappear when the dataset is activated/deactivated

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using `charts.js`.

This is my chart:
[image]

I have 3 or more datasets in the same chart, each with a different scale, let's image that all the scales are on the left.

As default when deactivating a dataset (for example in this case clicking on "Sold Products") the scale is rescaled between [-1, +1] as [here on multi-axis demo code](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html) too.

Is there a way in which I can make disappear the dataset's scale when that dataset is deactivated?
For example in this case if I deactivate "Sold Products", I would like to make the scale in the middle to disappear.
When I reactivate the "Sold Product" then I would like the scale to reappear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code.

You could use the `beforeLayout` hook as shown below. The function iterates over the datasets and sets the `yAxes.display` option depending whether the corresponding dataset is hidden or not.

```
plugins: [{
  beforeLayout: chart => chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = !ds._meta[0].hidden)
}],
```

Please have a look at the following runnable code snippet to see how it works.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: chart => chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = !ds._meta[0].hidden)
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        yAxisID: 'yAxis-1',
        data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69],
        borderColor: 'red',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        yAxisID: 'yAxis-2',
        data: [9, 6, 8, 7, 6],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 3',
        yAxisID: 'yAxis-3',
        data: [0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5],
        borderColor: 'green',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          id: 'yAxis-1',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
        },
        {
          id: 'yAxis-2',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left'
        },
        {
          id: 'yAxis-3',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```